# How to store the cookies from one session and restore the same cookies by refreshing the page in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have two input item one for the Option Select and Radio Button. Once the user selects the Option Select (say, the value is ABCD) and Radio button (say, the value is R).

Now the user refreshes the page and would like to pre-populate the page with a default value of Option Select (ABCD) and radio button (R).

I have been trying to use ngCookies. I can set and get the cookies from the same session. Once I refresh the page, the values become null.
such as $cookies.put('selectOption', $scope.selectValue) $cookies('radioSelection', $scope.radioValue)

TO get the value, $cookie.get('selectOption') and $cookie.get('radioSelection');

Basically, recreating the page with some default values.

Please help me out how I can achieve this one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are resetting your select box value each time you refresh so add an if statement like

```
if (!$cookie.get('selectOption') ) {
 $cookies.put('selectOption', $scope.selectValue) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are correct I am re-initializing the parameter which I didn't realize.

Comment: Can you then select as an answer ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to default the selection based on the cookie values.

Comment: I mean can you vote my answer and mark it as selected answer ?